# Show $\mathbb{E}{[\exp(-\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}I_{E_{n}}})] \leq \exp[-(1-e^{-1})\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}({E_{n}})]$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $E_{1}, E_{2}, \dots$ be independent events and $e^{-\infty} := 0$

> Show that $\mathbb{E}{[\exp(-\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}I_{E_{n}}})] \leq \exp[-(1-e^{-1})\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}({E_{n}})]$

We've recently learned Jensen's inequality but I can't think about a way of applying it here?

$\mathbb{E}{[\exp(-\sum_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}I_{E_{n}}})] = \mathbb{E}{[\prod_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}\exp(-I_{E_{n}}})] = \prod_{n \mathop = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}{[\exp(-I_{E_{n}}})]... $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\exp(-I_{E_n}) = e^{-1} I_{E_n}+ I_{E_n^c}$$ implies $$\mathbb{E}(\exp(-I_{E_n})) =(e^{-1}-1) \mathbb{P}(E_n)+1.$$ Now use that $$1+x \leq e^x.$$